# How do you move an unallocated partition?

Tags: partitioning

For the life of me I cannot figure out how to move this partition so I can add it onto my ubuntu partition. I need to move it down two partitions so it is next to sda8, then I can add those partitions together. I cannot edit it in anyway unless I make it into a partition, But even when I do that and try to "resize/move" It only allows me to re size it. I have no clue, I have been trying to do this for over an hour. I have tried with gparted, gparted booted from a USB, the windows drive editor, and even another drive editor I downloaded onto my windows drive. Please help, thanks :)

[image]

Comment: First, it's not a partition, it's unallocated space, second, you have nowhere to move it to, even if that was possible. To add that space to sda8, you'll need to move sda6, sda7 and sda8 up, then then resize/grow sda8. Perhaps, instead of moving multiple partitions, which will take very long, you could use the unallocated space as a separate home partition.

Comment: Check out [the manual](http://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual#gparted-move-partition) for more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (not sure if this will work or not):

Merge the unallocated space (you might have to convert this into a partition before merging) with sda6 , resize sda6 to its original size so as to give 97gb unallocated space *after* sda6. Merge this unallocated partition with sda7, resize sda7 to give 97gb unallocated space *after* sda7. Now see if you can merge this one with sda8.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that last night and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had to expand sda6 into the unallocated space, Then resize sda6 back to its original size. Then do that with the next partition, and then finally add it onto sda8.